# How to center the clippath from Fabric.js canvas when resizing the canvas and keep the objects on the same place in the clippath

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I made 2 buttons 1 to increase the canvas, and the other for decreasing it. When pressing one of these buttons I want to recenter all objects which where in the canvas and the clippath.

```
function vergrootcanvas(){
  canvas.setDimensions({ width: canvas.getWidth() * 1.2, height: canvas.getHeight() * 1.2 });
    canvas.centerObject(canvas.clipPath);
  canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
  canvas.centerObject(obj);
     });
    canvas.renderAll();

  
  }

  
    function verkleincanvas(){
  canvas.setDimensions({ width: canvas.getWidth() * 0.8, height: canvas.getHeight() * 0.8 });
    canvas.centerObject(canvas.clipPath);
   canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
    canvas.centerObject(obj);
  });
    canvas.renderAll();
  }
```

```
<div>
<button onclick="verkleincanvas()" style="background-color: #a0c637; color:white; border:none;">verklein canvas</button>
<button onclick="vergrootcanvas()" style="background-color: #a0c637; color:white; border:none;">vergroot canvas</button>
</div>


<div style="display:inline-block;">
<canvas id="canvas" width="500px"  height="500px" style="border:1px solid #000000; display:inline-block;"></canvas>
```

```
clipPath = new fabric.Rect({ width: 151.1 + 11.3, height: 113.3 + 11.3, top: 0, lockMovementX: true, lockMovementY: true, left: 0, stroke: '#40e0d0', strokeWidth: 1, hasControls: false, hasBorders: false, });
        canvas.clipPath = clipPath;
        canvas.centerObject(clipPath);
        canvas.renderAll();
        recta = new fabric.Rect({
          fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
          width: 151.1,
          height: 113.3,
          hasControls: false,
          hasRoatatingPoint: false,
          stroke: '#40e0d0',
          strokeWidth: 1,
          lockMovementX: true, lockMovementY: true

        });
        canvas.add(recta);
        canvas.centerObject(recta);
        canvas.renderAll();
```

It does work but I want to set the items on the same position in the clippath.

Comment: There's no clipPath in your code. Can you please add a working example showing the issue?

Comment: uploaded the clippath but i want when you add items and resize the canvas to keep the items(objects) on the same position where they stood in the canvas before the resize

Comment: please add a working code snippet https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example